# Oracle SQL WHEN condition in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have the following select statement (example) which gives back a sum from a table.

```
Select SUM(Salary) from Users d, MoreData m where
d.Office = 'A' and
m.Active = 'Yes' and
d.id_user = m.id_of_user
```

This works perfectly fine and adds up column salery for all users which are located in Office A abd are marked as active in the table MoreData.

Now I would only like to get a result if the SUM(Salary) under these conditions is greater than 1.000.000 EUR. If not the result would be just NULL.

Thanks in Advance

I tried adding an CASE WHEN statement but this always gives ORA-00900 back.

It needs to be an SELECT statement.

Comment: `ORA-00900` means your query isn't correct. Can you provide the query you have with your CASE WHEN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a `having` clause:

```
Select SUM(Salary) from Users d, MoreData m where
d.Office = 'A' and
m.Active = 'Yes' and
d.id_user = m.id_of_user
having sum(salary) > 1000000       --> this
```

Though, I presume that you'd actually want to get some more info, such as *which user has such a salary*, so you'd have to add that column into the `select` column list and then group by it. Also, to follow *good practice*, switch to `join`:

```
  SELECT d.id_user, 
         SUM (salary)
    FROM users d JOIN moredata m ON m.id_of_user = d.id_user
   WHERE     d.office = 'A'
         AND m.active = 'Yes'
GROUP BY d.id_user
  HAVING SUM (salary) > 1000000
```